# pulled down io protection from overvoltage

Tags: protection, pulldown, tvs, over-voltage-protection, io

I need to protect my IC's io form overvoltage(default is 5v). The pin has the capability to source 10 mA and sink 25mA

I tought of using a tvs diode(between pin and gnd) and a resistor(330r from pin to output connector).

The problem is i also want the pin as low when there are no input. So i used a pulldown resistor(10k).

I have the schematic here
[image]

Is this a good idea? If not how can i make it better. Any ideas?

Comment: this may help ... http://wiki.t-o-f.info/uploads/Arduino/10ways_to_destroy_an_arduino.pdf

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! I have read that docment recently. The pulldown resistor is what got me confused.

Comment: What are you connecting this circuit to?

Comment: I connect the circuit to an IC. PCA9698's io pin. the output goes to connector. The user might connect anything that can be used by an io pin.